# Inductor calculations helper script and motor idea

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

I have an idea for a motor involving the use of a flyback transformer to recycle EMF in a custom designed pole-to-pole repulsion-attraction DC motor. I wrote a script to help with setting design targets and I did my best with what I know to make it accurate and I want to share it (also make sure it is correct). I think it's right, I can't input any numbers that make the energy storage and retrieval anything more than ~70% efficiency, but I heard flyback transformers can do better than that.....makes me want to ask for help, AI tools say it looks right, maybe I didn't plug in the right values yet....

I call the idea a "reactance" motor. Basically, the idea is to make a flyback circuit an integral part of opperation cycle. The idea being to make high inductance coils to get a higher RL time constant. It would opperate on DC and use a Pole-to-Pole arrangement for the rotor and stators. The commutation cycle would be + voltage, flyback, - voltage, flyback. For example If my I have a rotational speed target of 30 Hz and I have 6 rotor and stator poles then I would have to switch the poles every 5.55 milliseconds so I would base my RL time constant off of that timing. But I need to know what my targets are.

The theoretical advantage is that normally the "E = 1/2 * L * I^2" of energy that's stored in the magnetic field is capture instead of just thrown away as EMF and heat. It shouldn't just be wasted and trown to the wind, it should be efficiently captured and stored for the next attraction-repulsion phase. That's my theory any ways. I want to test if it's worth looking into with a practical device. But I want to make sure I can plan the device somewhat.

What do you guys think of the script?
What do you guys think of my motor idea?

I worked on it for a while and I used AI tools to debug it as much as possible, but I still want to give it to other people and I still want to make sure that it is correct.

```
# The following is a quick little program for helping to determin how much energy is stored in an
# inductors magnetic field considering the inductors resistace, inductance and applied voltage and power on time as a multiple of RL time constants

import tkinter as tk
import math

def format_engineering(value):
    """Formats the number into engineering notation with four significant figures."""
    if value == 0:
        return "0.0000"
    else:
        for exponent in range(-12, 12, 3):
            if abs(value) < 10**(exponent + 3):
                return f"{value / 10**exponent:.4f}e{exponent}"
        return f"{value:.4e}"

def current_peek_for_time_powered(time_constants):
    """
    Calculates the current as a percentage of its maximum value for a given number of time constants.

    :param time_constants: Number of time constants
    :return: Current value as a percentage of its maximum value
    """
    percentage = (1 - math.exp(-time_constants))
    return percentage

def calculate_values():
    try:
        R = float(resistance_entry.get())
        V = float(voltage_entry.get())
        L = float(inductance_entry.get())
        nT = float(no_taus_entry.get())

        I = V / R
        tau = L / R  # Time constant: ~1/5th the time it takes for an inductors current flow to settle
        peek_current = current_peek_for_time_powered(nT) * I  # current flow per
        E_in = 0.0

        # 1 watt-second = 1 joule and E_in must be calculated in watt seconds
        # Using RMS calculations for the transient phase of powering the inductor
        # Using a combonation of RMS and steady current flow for time periods where
        # the inductor has enough time for the current flow to settle out
        if (nT <= 5.0): # If The power on time is less than 5 time constants
            E_in = 2**-0.5 * peek_current * V * (tau * nT) # RMS Energy
        else:
            E_in = 2**-0.5 * peek_current * V * (5.0 * tau)# RMS energy during transient phase of inductor opperation
            E_in += peek_current * V * (tau * (nT-5.0)) # steady discharge energy
        E_out = 0.5 * L * peek_current**2  # Flyback Energy

        time_constant_label.config(text=f"Time Constant (τ): {format_engineering(tau)} s")
        power_time_label.config(text=f"Power On Time (τ * # constants): {format_engineering(tau * nT)} s")
        E_in_label.config(text=f"Input Energy (E_in): {format_engineering(E_in)} J")
        E_out_label.config(text=f"Output Energy (E_out): {format_engineering(E_out)} J")
        efficiency_label.config(text=f"Efficiency: {(E_out/E_in)*100.0} %")
    except ValueError:
        pass

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Motor Energy Calculator")
root.geometry("400x300")

# Create entry fields
resistance_entry = tk.Entry(root)
voltage_entry = tk.Entry(root)
inductance_entry = tk.Entry(root)
no_taus_entry = tk.Entry(root)

# Create labels
resistance_label = tk.Label(root, text="Resistance (R) in Ohms:")
voltage_label = tk.Label(root, text="Voltage (V) in Volts:")
inductance_label = tk.Label(root, text="Inductance (L) in Henries:")
no_taus_label = tk.Label(root, text="Number of Time Constants:")

time_constant_label = tk.Label(root, text="Time Constant (τ):")
power_time_label = tk.Label(root, text="Power On Time (τ * # constants):")
E_in_label = tk.Label(root, text="Input Energy (E_in):")
E_out_label = tk.Label(root, text="Output Energy (E_out):")
efficiency_label = tk.Label(root, text="Efficiency:")

# Create a calculate button
calculate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculate_values)

# Layout the components in the window
resistance_label.pack()
resistance_entry.pack()

voltage_label.pack()
voltage_entry.pack()

inductance_label.pack()
inductance_entry.pack()

no_taus_label.pack()
no_taus_entry.pack()

calculate_button.pack()

time_constant_label.pack()
power_time_label.pack()
E_in_label.pack()
E_out_label.pack()
efficiency_label.pack()

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```